# query execution with prepared statements not working

Tags: php, mysqli

i am using ajax to display dynamic data on my website! previously it was done using simple mysqli queries now i am improving my website's security by adding prepared statements,i have two queries one is written in mysqli and other in prepared statements here's the mysqli query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT model_trim FROM `tbl_02_models` WHERE model_year='$year' and model_name='$model' and model_make_id='$make' ";
    $run = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        if($row['model_trim']){
        $data2[$i]['model_trim']=$row['model_trim'];
        $i++;
        }
    }
```

and here's the prepared statement query

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT model_trim FROM `tbl_02_models` WHERE model_year=? and model_name=? and model_make_id=?";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                if($stmt){

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_param("iss",$year,$model,$make);
                    $stmt->bind_result($model_trim);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
                    {
                        if($model_trim)
                        {
                        $data2[$i]['model_trim']=$model_trim;
                        $i++;
                        }

                    }
                        $stmt->close();                 
                    }
```

the query written in simple mysqli is working fine but when i am using the same query in prepared statements it is returning me null! any idea?

Comment: You need to execute _after_ you've bound the params...

Comment: Today i saw an angel! thanks @JonStirling

Comment: could you write your answer in separate comment so i can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute method is called after bind the comments.

Try below code :

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT model_trim FROM `tbl_02_models` WHERE model_year=? and model_name=? and model_make_id=?";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                if($stmt){

                    $stmt->bind_param("iss",$year,$model,$make);
                    $stmt->bind_result($model_trim);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
                    {
                        if($model_trim)
                        {
                        $data2[$i]['model_trim']=$model_trim;
                        $i++;
                        }

                    }

                        $stmt->close();                 
                    }
```

For more reference follow this link - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp